# Why didn't std::for_each + lambda work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, lambda, operator-overloading

It's an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th Edition*:

> Exercise 14.7: Define an output operator for you **String** class you
>   wrote for the exercises in § 13.5 (p. 531).(Page 558)

The `string.h` I wrote for previous exercises:

```
/**
 * @brief std::string like class without template
 *
 *        design:
 *
 *        [0][1][2][3][unconstructed chars][unallocated memory]
 *        ^           ^                    ^
 *        elements    first_free           cap
 */
class String
{
    friend  std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const String& s);

public:
    //! default constructor
    String();

    //! constructor taking C-style string i.e. a char array terminated with'\0'.
    explicit String(const char * const c);

    //! copy constructor
    explicit String(const String& s);

    //! move constructor    --07.Jan.2014
    String(String&& s) noexcept;

    //! operator =
    String& operator = (const String& rhs);

    //! move operator =     --07.Jan.2014
    String& operator = (String&& rhs) noexcept;

    //! destructor
    ~String();

    //! members
    char* begin() const  { return elements;   }
    char* end()   const  { return first_free; }

    std::size_t size()     const {return first_free - elements;  }
    std::size_t capacity() const {return cap - elements;         }

private:

    //! data members
    char* elements;
    char* first_free;
    char* cap;

    std::allocator<char> alloc;

    //! utillities for big 3
    void free();    
};

std::ostream&
operator << (std::ostream& os, const String& s);
```

Part of the `string.cpp`:

```
//! constructor taking C-style string i.e. a char array terminated with'\0'.
String::String(const char *  const c)
{
    auto p = c;
    char* newData = alloc.allocate(sizeof(p));

    std::uninitialized_copy(p, (p + sizeof(p)), newData);

    //! build the data structure
    elements = newData;
    cap = first_free = newData + sizeof(c);
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const String &s)
{
    std::for_each(&s.elements, &s.first_free, [&](const char* p){
        os << *p;
    });

    return os;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    String s("1234");
    std::cout << s <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Why is the output like so? why not `1234`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because `elements` points to an array of `char`, so each element is a `char`, not a `char*`.

You also need to drop the `&` in front of `s.elements` and `s.first_free`, because you are interested in the addresses the pointers point to, not the addresses of the pointers themselves.

So, this code would work:

```
std::for_each(s.elements, s.first_free, [&](char p){
    os << p;
});
```

As mentioned by @TemplateRex in comments, it would be both cleaner and more idiomatic to use the `begin()` and `end()` member functions:

```
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](char p){ os << p; });
```

Comment: `std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), ...)` is of course much clearer

Comment: @TemplateRex the code sample is too long for my limited attention span, so I didn't get there :)

Comment: Leaky abstractions should always get your attention ;-)

Comment: @juanchopanza You are right . But seems no `&` before `s.elements` nor `s.first_free`.

Comment: @Alan.W Good catch. I added an explanation as to why this is the case.

Comment: @juanchopanza absolutly

Comment: Re. the downvote, if there is something wrong with the answer I'd like to know so I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(pointer)` where `pointer` is a `char const*` does not return the length of an array.  You make this mistake multiple times.  Use `strlen` instead. This is hidden because your string is 4 char long, and on a 32 bit system `sizeof(ptr)` is 4.

Next `&first_free` and similar in your `for_each` should be just `first_free`.

Next your lambda should take `char` not `char*`s.  Then the output should be `<< p` not `<< *p`.

You should create both `const` and non-`const` `begin` and `end`.  `const` returns `char const *`, while non `const` returns `char*` -- containers that logically own their underlying data should use `const` that way for iteration.

Next replace your `for_eaxh` to use `begin()` and `end()` like `for_each( x.begin(), x.end(),` ... -- no need to redo what `begin` and `end` do.  In C++11 you can even use a ranged based `for`:

```
for(char c : s ) {
  std::cout << c
}
```

instead of `for_each`.

Comment: Many many thanks. Without your answer, I would never notice these mistakes you point out, esp the wrongly using of `sizeof`.